# Momentjs Range returning False

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to use Moment to find out if a date is inbetween 2 dates using the Moment Range plugin:
https://github.com/rotaready/moment-range#contains

For some reason, my code below is always throwing out False.  Here is an example of the output:

> START: 2015-01-01 00:00:00 END: 2017-08-01 00:00:00 CLOSED: 2017-06-08
>   17:59:56 DECISION: false

You can clearly see here that the closed date falls between the start and end date, yet I am told it does not

Here is my code:

```
let end = moment('2017-08-01 00:00:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
let start = moment('2015-01-01 00:00:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
let closedDate = moment('2017-06-08 17:59:56').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
let range = moment.range(start, end)

console.log(`START:`,start,'END:',end,'CLOSED:',closedDate,'DECISION:',range.contains(closedDate));
```

Comment: why dont you use the [isBetween](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/) method? I know its pure momentjs, but it could work

Comment: Wow, ok I totally missed that method when looking at their docs.  Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this using the within function, and also changing the how I format the moment objects

```
let end = moment('2017-08-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
let start = moment('2015-01-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
let closedDate = moment('2017-06-08 17:59:56','YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
let range = moment.range(start, end)
console.log(`START:`,start,'END:',end,'CLOSED:',closedDate,'DECISION:',closedDate.within(range));
```

Comment: moment.format() returns string, and contains expects js Date, so range.contains(closedDate.toDate()) would work with those new declarations.